# Angular 2 Access Component Defined by Template

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-directives

I'm using Ionic as an example for this, but I figure it's a general Angular 2 question.

**page1.ts**

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-angular';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/page1/page1.html'
})
export class Page1 {
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

**page1.html**

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <ion-title>Tab 1</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content padding class="page1">
  <ion-slides pager>
     <ion-slide>
       <h3>Thank you for choosing the Awesome App!</h3>
       <p>
         The number one app for everything awesome.
       </p>
     </ion-slide>
     <ion-slide>
       <h3>Using Awesome</h3>
        <div id="list">
          <h5>Just three steps:</h5>
          <ol>
            <li>Be awesome</li>
            <li>Stay awesome</li>
            <li>There is no step 3</li>
          </ol>
        </div>
     </ion-slide>
     <ion-slide>
       <h3>Any questions?</h3>
     </ion-slide>
   </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

How do I programatically reference the `ion-slides` object from the constructor of the Page1 class?

I had assumed via some sort of #reference but I'm not sure of the syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `ion-slides` is a component or a directive, and there is only one instance in the template, use @ViewChild:

```
@ViewChild(IonSlides) ionSlides:IonSlides;
```

This assumes the component class name is `IonSlides`.

`this.ionSlides` will not be available in the constructor.  It will be available in lifecycle hook `ngAfterViewInit()`, as documented in the [ViewChild API page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html):

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   console.log(this.ionSlides);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's an angular question.You can use @ViewChild decorator to access child component. like:

```
@ViewChild(CountdownTimerComponent)
  private _timerComponent:CountdownTimerComponent;
```

See the angular2 doc for the detail, not to hard.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child

PS. if you have more than on components in same type like Button, use

```
@ViewChildren(Button) buttons: QueryList<Button>;
```